# Webpack output is empty object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, webpack

I want to build a react component library as a node module to then import it into different projects. But if I try to import a component it just returns an empty object.

button.jsx:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'

export class Button extends Component {

   render() {
       return <button className='btn'>Hello Button comp</button>
   }
}

export default Button
```

index.js

```
var Button = require('./button/button').default;

module.exports  = {
   Button: Button
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
const Path = require('path');

module.exports = {
   resolve: {
      extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
   },
   entry: {
      app: './src/components/index.js'
   },
   output: {
      path: __dirname,
      filename: 'bundle.js'
   },
   module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.jsx$/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            query: {
                presets: [
                    'es2015',
                    'react'
                ]
            },
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            include: [
                Path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')
            ]
        },
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            query: {
                presets: [
                    'es2015',
                    'react'
                ]
            },
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            include: [
                Path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')
            ]
        }
    ]
  }
}
```

Main property in package.json is bundle.js

I figured out that when I import Button in a project it is just an empty object. It seems to me as if webpack doesn't bundle the index file properly. Any ideas what could be wrong here?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

A webpack bundle does not expose your exports by default, as it assumes that you're building an app and not a library (which is the far more common use of webpack). You can create a library by configuring [`output.library`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#output-library) and [`output.libraryTarget`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#output-librarytarget).

```
output: {
   path: __dirname,
   filename: 'bundle.js',
   library: 'yourLibName',
   libraryTarget: 'commonjs2'
},
```

`output.libraryTarget` is the format of the module, which would also allow you to expose the library as a global variable. `commonjs2` is the module format that Node uses. See [What is commonjs2?](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/1114) for the difference between `commonjs` and `commonjs2`.

Since you're using React, you'll expect that the consumer of the library will have React present as a dependency and therefore you don't want to include it in your bundle. To do that you can define it as an [External](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/). This is shown in [Authoring Libraries](https://webpack.js.org/guides/author-libraries/), which walks you through a small example.

Comment: Thank you! For those running into the same issue because they are exporting multiple files look here: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/tree/master/examples/multi-part-library

Comment: Does that apply also for a library that will be used in a browser (with the script tag, not in react)? I'm facing the same issue and I tried all libraryTarget's values and it always outputs an empty object.

Comment: Thanks for this! The bit about libraries and apps is pretty significant IMO, because the majority(actually almost all that I've seen) of examples on the net are apps and not libraries.

Comment: And what if my app has a file with default export? Should I just turn the whole thing into "library" because of that?

Comment: thank you for this, i wasted a few hours pulling my hair out wondering why the d.ts has my export but it fails on runtime (fyi im building  a ts/js sdk library)