# using a module in another module. module.exports is empty object

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack-2, node-modules

I have a module that I would like to use in a different project.  It is compiled using webpack3.  In the second project I've linked to the first module and that seems to work, except when I require the module, it always comes back as an empty object.

**tsconfig options**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "strict": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "lib": [
      "es2015"
    ]
  }
}
```

**dist/index.js (shortened)**

```
/******/ ([
/* 0 */
/***/ (function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

"use strict";

Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
var Test = /** @class */ (function () {
    function Test() {
    }
    Test.prototype.test = function () {
        console.log('works');
    };
    return Test;
}());
exports.Test = Test;


/***/ })
/******/ ]);
```

**package.json (shortened)**

```
{
   "main": "dist/index.js",
}
```

What this boils down to is a module called "test", a class called `Test` that also includes a method called `Test`.

If I run `module.exports` on the first project, it's an empty object.

In the second project that has linked to it and has it in it's node modules.

```
const test = require("test");
console.log(test); // {}
```

If I copy the code from another node module, and paste it overtop of the `dist/index.js`, it does return what is expected.

- Does the exported webpack config need to also be imported via webpack?  I want it to be used in many projects regardless of if they are using webpack.

Thanks for any help, I feel like I'm almost have it but I'm not quite there.

Answer (score 1):

maybe this github issue can help you

[Can't require bundle on node.js](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2268)

set these in the webpack config file

```
target: "node" 
output.libraryTarget: "commonjs"
```

Comment: I tried this out but it didn't change anything it seems.  Thanks for answering though

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

It's important to outline the package in your webpack.config

https://stackoverflow.com/a/44542254/3425961