# React.createElement: type is invalid error after bundling and importing react component to another react app

Tags: reactjs, webpack, components, bundle, babeljs

I am developing a set of reusable components and I am getting the error `React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.` after bundling and importing to another `react` compoponent as follows,

```
import Label from 'path/to/bundle/dist/Label';
```

I tried importing the unbundled component in the `src` folder (the `Label` component as shown below) by providing the path and it works fine. As soon as I bundle, and point to the bundled file it throws the above error.

Any help what maybe causing this is much apprecated!

The code base for, the bundled/unbundled component, webpack config, babelrc and devdependencies for babel and webpack are listed below.

NOTE: this is a package with a multiple entry points. if this info makes any difference :)

The implementation of the reusable component (`Label`) is as follows,

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const Label = (props) => {
  const {
    id,
    className,
    children,
    ...other
  } = props;

  return (
    <label id={id} className={className} {...other}>{children}</label>
  );
};

export default Label;

Label.propTypes = {
  id: PropTypes.string,
  className: PropTypes.string,
  children: PropTypes.node,
};

Label.defaultProps = {
  id: '',
  className: '',
  children: null,
};
```

the `.babelrc` file,

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "env", "react", "stage-2"],
  "plugins": ["transform-es2015-arrow-functions", "check-es2015-constants", "transform-es2015-block-scoping"]
}
```

the `wbepack.config.js` file

```
const path = require('path');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const fs = require('fs');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    Label: 'path/to/Label',
    Button: 'path/to/Button',
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: '[name]/index.js',
  },
  optimization:{
    minimize: false, 
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.(svg|jpe?g|png|gif)$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'file-loader',
          options: {
            emitFile: false,
            name: '[path][name].[ext]',
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [new CleanWebpackPlugin()],
};
```

the babel and webpack `devDependencies`,

```
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
    "babel-plugin-check-es2015-constants": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-arrow-functions": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-block-scoping": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
    "webpack": "^4.30.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.1"
```

the code after bundling is as follows,

```
/******/ (function(modules) { // webpackBootstrap
/******/    // The module cache
/******/    var installedModules = {};
/******/
/******/    // The require function
/******/    function __webpack_require__(moduleId) {
/******/
/******/        // Check if module is in cache
/******/        if(installedModules[moduleId]) {
/******/            return installedModules[moduleId].exports;
/******/        }
/******/        // Create a new module (and put it into the cache)
/******/        var module = installedModules[moduleId] = {
/******/            i: moduleId,
/******/            l: false,
/******/            exports: {}
/******/        };
/******/
/******/        // Execute the module function
/******/        modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, __webpack_require__);
/******/
/******/        // Flag the module as loaded
/******/        module.l = true;
/******/
/******/        // Return the exports of the module
/******/        return module.exports;
/******/    }
/******/
/******/
/******/    // expose the modules object (__webpack_modules__)
/******/    __webpack_require__.m = modules;
/******/
/******/    // expose the module cache
/******/    __webpack_require__.c = installedModules;
/******/
/******/    // define getter function for harmony exports
/******/    __webpack_require__.d = function(exports, name, getter) {
/******/        if(!__webpack_require__.o(exports, name)) {
/******/            Object.defineProperty(exports, name, { enumerable: true, get: getter });
/******/        }
/******/    };
/******/
/******/    // define __esModule on exports
/******/    __webpack_require__.r = function(exports) {
/******/        if(typeof Symbol !== 'undefined' && Symbol.toStringTag) {
/******/            Object.defineProperty(exports, Symbol.toStringTag, { value: 'Module' });
/******/        }
/******/        Object.defineProperty(exports, '__esModule', { value: true });
/******/    };
/******/
/******/    // create a fake namespace object
/******/    // mode & 1: value is a module id, require it
/******/    // mode & 2: merge all properties of value into the ns
/******/    // mode & 4: return value when already ns object
/******/    // mode & 8|1: behave like require
/******/    __webpack_require__.t = function(value, mode) {
/******/        if(mode & 1) value = __webpack_require__(value);
/******/        if(mode & 8) return value;
/******/        if((mode & 4) && typeof value === 'object' && value && value.__esModule) return value;
/******/        var ns = Object.create(null);
/******/        __webpack_require__.r(ns);
/******/        Object.defineProperty(ns, 'default', { enumerable: true, value: value });
/******/        if(mode & 2 && typeof value != 'string') for(var key in value) __webpack_require__.d(ns, key, function(key) { return value[key]; }.bind(null, key));
/******/        return ns;
/******/    };
/******/
/******/    // getDefaultExport function for compatibility with non-harmony modules
/******/    __webpack_require__.n = function(module) {
/******/        var getter = module && module.__esModule ?
/******/            function getDefault() { return module['default']; } :
/******/            function getModuleExports() { return module; };
/******/        __webpack_require__.d(getter, 'a', getter);
/******/        return getter;
/******/    };
/******/
/******/    // Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call
/******/    __webpack_require__.o = function(object, property) { return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(object, property); };
/******/
/******/    // __webpack_public_path__
/******/    __webpack_require__.p = "";
/******/
/******/
/******/    // Load entry module and return exports
/******/    return __webpack_require__(__webpack_require__.s = 8);
/******/ })
/************************************************************************/
/******/ ([
/* 0 */
/***/ (function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

"use strict";


if (true) {
  module.exports = __webpack_require__(2);
} else {}


/***/ }),
/* 1 */
/***/ (function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

/**
 * Copyright (c) 2013-present, Facebook, Inc.
 *
 * This source code is licensed under the MIT license found in the
 * LICENSE file in the root directory of this source tree.
 */

if (false) { var throwOnDirectAccess, ReactIs; } else {
  // By explicitly using `prop-types` you are opting into new production behavior.
  module.exports = __webpack_require__(4)();
}


/***/ }),
/* 2 */
/***/ (function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

"use strict";
/** @license React v16.8.6
 * react.production.min.js
 *
 * Copyright (c) Facebook, Inc. and its affiliates.
 *
 * This source code is licensed under the MIT license found in the
 * LICENSE file in the root directory of this source tree.
 */

var k=__webpack_require__(3),n="function"===typeof Symbol&&Symbol.for,p=n?Symbol.for("react.element"):60103,q=n?Symbol.for("react.portal"):60106,r=n?Symbol.for("react.fragment"):60107,t=n?Symbol.for("react.strict_mode"):60108,u=n?Symbol.for("react.profiler"):60114,v=n?Symbol.for("react.provider"):60109,w=n?Symbol.for("react.context"):60110,x=n?Symbol.for("react.concurrent_mode"):60111,y=n?Symbol.for("react.forward_ref"):60112,z=n?Symbol.for("react.suspense"):60113,aa=n?Symbol.for("react.memo"):
60115,ba=n?Symbol.for("react.lazy"):60116,A="function"===typeof Symbol&&Symbol.iterator;function ca(a,b,d,c,e,g,h,f){if(!a){a=void 0;if(void 0===b)a=Error("Minified exception occurred; use the non-minified dev environment for the full error message and additional helpful warnings.");else{var l=[d,c,e,g,h,f],m=0;a=Error(b.replace(/%s/g,function(){return l[m++]}));a.name="Invariant Violation"}a.framesToPop=1;throw a;}}
function B(a){for(var b=arguments.length-1,d="https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant="+a,c=0;c<b;c++)d+="&args[]="+encodeURIComponent(arguments[c+1]);ca(!1,"Minified React error #"+a+"; visit %s for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings. ",d)}var C={isMounted:function(){return!1},enqueueForceUpdate:function(){},enqueueReplaceState:function(){},enqueueSetState:function(){}},D={};
function E(a,b,d){this.props=a;this.context=b;this.refs=D;this.updater=d||C}E.prototype.isReactComponent={};E.prototype.setState=function(a,b){"object"!==typeof a&&"function"!==typeof a&&null!=a?B("85"):void 0;this.updater.enqueueSetState(this,a,b,"setState")};E.prototype.forceUpdate=function(a){this.updater.enqueueForceUpdate(this,a,"forceUpdate")};function F(){}F.prototype=E.prototype;function G(a,b,d){this.props=a;this.context=b;this.refs=D;this.updater=d||C}var H=G.prototype=new F;
H.constructor=G;k(H,E.prototype);H.isPureReactComponent=!0;var I={current:null},J={current:null},K=Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty,L={key:!0,ref:!0,__self:!0,__source:!0};
function M(a,b,d){var c=void 0,e={},g=null,h=null;if(null!=b)for(c in void 0!==b.ref&&(h=b.ref),void 0!==b.key&&(g=""+b.key),b)K.call(b,c)&&!L.hasOwnProperty(c)&&(e[c]=b[c]);var f=arguments.length-2;if(1===f)e.children=d;else if(1<f){for(var l=Array(f),m=0;m<f;m++)l[m]=arguments[m+2];e.children=l}if(a&&a.defaultProps)for(c in f=a.defaultProps,f)void 0===e[c]&&(e[c]=f[c]);return{$$typeof:p,type:a,key:g,ref:h,props:e,_owner:J.current}}
function da(a,b){return{$$typeof:p,type:a.type,key:b,ref:a.ref,props:a.props,_owner:a._owner}}function N(a){return"object"===typeof a&&null!==a&&a.$$typeof===p}function escape(a){var b={"=":"=0",":":"=2"};return"$"+(""+a).replace(/[=:]/g,function(a){return b[a]})}var O=/\/+/g,P=[];function Q(a,b,d,c){if(P.length){var e=P.pop();e.result=a;e.keyPrefix=b;e.func=d;e.context=c;e.count=0;return e}return{result:a,keyPrefix:b,func:d,context:c,count:0}}
function R(a){a.result=null;a.keyPrefix=null;a.func=null;a.context=null;a.count=0;10>P.length&&P.push(a)}
function S(a,b,d,c){var e=typeof a;if("undefined"===e||"boolean"===e)a=null;var g=!1;if(null===a)g=!0;else switch(e){case "string":case "number":g=!0;break;case "object":switch(a.$$typeof){case p:case q:g=!0}}if(g)return d(c,a,""===b?"."+T(a,0):b),1;g=0;b=""===b?".":b+":";if(Array.isArray(a))for(var h=0;h<a.length;h++){e=a[h];var f=b+T(e,h);g+=S(e,f,d,c)}else if(null===a||"object"!==typeof a?f=null:(f=A&&a[A]||a["@@iterator"],f="function"===typeof f?f:null),"function"===typeof f)for(a=f.call(a),h=
0;!(e=a.next()).done;)e=e.value,f=b+T(e,h++),g+=S(e,f,d,c);else"object"===e&&(d=""+a,B("31","[object Object]"===d?"object with keys {"+Object.keys(a).join(", ")+"}":d,""));return g}function U(a,b,d){return null==a?0:S(a,"",b,d)}function T(a,b){return"object"===typeof a&&null!==a&&null!=a.key?escape(a.key):b.toString(36)}function ea(a,b){a.func.call(a.context,b,a.count++)}
function fa(a,b,d){var c=a.result,e=a.keyPrefix;a=a.func.call(a.context,b,a.count++);Array.isArray(a)?V(a,c,d,function(a){return a}):null!=a&&(N(a)&&(a=da(a,e+(!a.key||b&&b.key===a.key?"":(""+a.key).replace(O,"$&/")+"/")+d)),c.push(a))}function V(a,b,d,c,e){var g="";null!=d&&(g=(""+d).replace(O,"$&/")+"/");b=Q(b,g,c,e);U(a,fa,b);R(b)}function W(){var a=I.current;null===a?B("321"):void 0;return a}
var X={Children:{map:function(a,b,d){if(null==a)return a;var c=[];V(a,c,null,b,d);return c},forEach:function(a,b,d){if(null==a)return a;b=Q(null,null,b,d);U(a,ea,b);R(b)},count:function(a){return U(a,function(){return null},null)},toArray:function(a){var b=[];V(a,b,null,function(a){return a});return b},only:function(a){N(a)?void 0:B("143");return a}},createRef:function(){return{current:null}},Component:E,PureComponent:G,createContext:function(a,b){void 0===b&&(b=null);a={$$typeof:w,_calculateChangedBits:b,
_currentValue:a,_currentValue2:a,_threadCount:0,Provider:null,Consumer:null};a.Provider={$$typeof:v,_context:a};return a.Consumer=a},forwardRef:function(a){return{$$typeof:y,render:a}},lazy:function(a){return{$$typeof:ba,_ctor:a,_status:-1,_result:null}},memo:function(a,b){return{$$typeof:aa,type:a,compare:void 0===b?null:b}},useCallback:function(a,b){return W().useCallback(a,b)},useContext:function(a,b){return W().useContext(a,b)},useEffect:function(a,b){return W().useEffect(a,b)},useImperativeHandle:function(a,
b,d){return W().useImperativeHandle(a,b,d)},useDebugValue:function(){},useLayoutEffect:function(a,b){return W().useLayoutEffect(a,b)},useMemo:function(a,b){return W().useMemo(a,b)},useReducer:function(a,b,d){return W().useReducer(a,b,d)},useRef:function(a){return W().useRef(a)},useState:function(a){return W().useState(a)},Fragment:r,StrictMode:t,Suspense:z,createElement:M,cloneElement:function(a,b,d){null===a||void 0===a?B("267",a):void 0;var c=void 0,e=k({},a.props),g=a.key,h=a.ref,f=a._owner;if(null!=
b){void 0!==b.ref&&(h=b.ref,f=J.current);void 0!==b.key&&(g=""+b.key);var l=void 0;a.type&&a.type.defaultProps&&(l=a.type.defaultProps);for(c in b)K.call(b,c)&&!L.hasOwnProperty(c)&&(e[c]=void 0===b[c]&&void 0!==l?l[c]:b[c])}c=arguments.length-2;if(1===c)e.children=d;else if(1<c){l=Array(c);for(var m=0;m<c;m++)l[m]=arguments[m+2];e.children=l}return{$$typeof:p,type:a.type,key:g,ref:h,props:e,_owner:f}},createFactory:function(a){var b=M.bind(null,a);b.type=a;return b},isValidElement:N,version:"16.8.6",
unstable_ConcurrentMode:x,unstable_Profiler:u,__SECRET_INTERNALS_DO_NOT_USE_OR_YOU_WILL_BE_FIRED:{ReactCurrentDispatcher:I,ReactCurrentOwner:J,assign:k}},Y={default:X},Z=Y&&X||Y;module.exports=Z.default||Z;


/***/ }),
/* 3 */
/***/ (function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

"use strict";
/*
object-assign
(c) Sindre Sorhus
@license MIT
*/


/* eslint-disable no-unused-vars */
var getOwnPropertySymbols = Object.getOwnPropertySymbols;
var hasOwnProperty = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty;
var propIsEnumerable = Object.prototype.propertyIsEnumerable;

function toObject(val) {
    if (val === null || val === undefined) {
        throw new TypeError('Object.assign cannot be called with null or undefined');
    }

    return Object(val);
}

function shouldUseNative() {
    try {
        if (!Object.assign) {
            return false;
        }

        // Detect buggy property enumeration order in older V8 versions.

        // https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=4118
        var test1 = new String('abc');  // eslint-disable-line no-new-wrappers
        test1[5] = 'de';
        if (Object.getOwnPropertyNames(test1)[0] === '5') {
            return false;
        }

        // https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=3056
        var test2 = {};
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            test2['_' + String.fromCharCode(i)] = i;
        }
        var order2 = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(test2).map(function (n) {
            return test2[n];
        });
        if (order2.join('') !== '0123456789') {
            return false;
        }

        // https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=3056
        var test3 = {};
        'abcdefghijklmnopqrst'.split('').forEach(function (letter) {
            test3[letter] = letter;
        });
        if (Object.keys(Object.assign({}, test3)).join('') !==
                'abcdefghijklmnopqrst') {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    } catch (err) {
        // We don't expect any of the above to throw, but better to be safe.
        return false;
    }
}

module.exports = shouldUseNative() ? Object.assign : function (target, source) {
    var from;
    var to = toObject(target);
    var symbols;

    for (var s = 1; s < arguments.length; s++) {
        from = Object(arguments[s]);

        for (var key in from) {
            if (hasOwnProperty.call(from, key)) {
                to[key] = from[key];
            }
        }

        if (getOwnPropertySymbols) {
            symbols = getOwnPropertySymbols(from);
            for (var i = 0; i < symbols.length; i++) {
                if (propIsEnumerable.call(from, symbols[i])) {
                    to[symbols[i]] = from[symbols[i]];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return to;
};


/***/ }),
/* 4 */
/***/ (function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

"use strict";
/**
 * Copyright (c) 2013-present, Facebook, Inc.
 *
 * This source code is licensed under the MIT license found in the
 * LICENSE file in the root directory of this source tree.
 */



var ReactPropTypesSecret = __webpack_require__(5);

function emptyFunction() {}
function emptyFunctionWithReset() {}
emptyFunctionWithReset.resetWarningCache = emptyFunction;

module.exports = function() {
  function shim(props, propName, componentName, location, propFullName, secret) {
    if (secret === ReactPropTypesSecret) {
      // It is still safe when called from React.
      return;
    }
    var err = new Error(
      'Calling PropTypes validators directly is not supported by the `prop-types` package. ' +
      'Use PropTypes.checkPropTypes() to call them. ' +
      'Read more at'
    );
    err.name = 'Invariant Violation';
    throw err;
  };
  shim.isRequired = shim;
  function getShim() {
    return shim;
  };
  // Important!
  // Keep this list in sync with production version in `./factoryWithTypeCheckers.js`.
  var ReactPropTypes = {
    array: shim,
    bool: shim,
    func: shim,
    number: shim,
    object: shim,
    string: shim,
    symbol: shim,

    any: shim,
    arrayOf: getShim,
    element: shim,
    elementType: shim,
    instanceOf: getShim,
    node: shim,
    objectOf: getShim,
    oneOf: getShim,
    oneOfType: getShim,
    shape: getShim,
    exact: getShim,

    checkPropTypes: emptyFunctionWithReset,
    resetWarningCache: emptyFunction
  };

  ReactPropTypes.PropTypes = ReactPropTypes;

  return ReactPropTypes;
};


/***/ }),
/* 5 */
/***/ (function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

"use strict";
/**
 * Copyright (c) 2013-present, Facebook, Inc.
 *
 * This source code is licensed under the MIT license found in the
 * LICENSE file in the root directory of this source tree.
 */



var ReactPropTypesSecret = 'SECRET_DO_NOT_PASS_THIS_OR_YOU_WILL_BE_FIRED';

module.exports = ReactPropTypesSecret;


/***/ }),
/* 6 */,
/* 7 */,
/* 8 */
/***/ (function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

"use strict";


Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
  value: true
});

var _extends = Object.assign || function (target) { for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) { var source = arguments[i]; for (var key in source) { if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(source, key)) { target[key] = source[key]; } } } return target; };

var _react = __webpack_require__(0);

var _react2 = _interopRequireDefault(_react);

var _propTypes = __webpack_require__(1);

var _propTypes2 = _interopRequireDefault(_propTypes);

function _interopRequireDefault(obj) { return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : { default: obj }; }

function _objectWithoutProperties(obj, keys) { var target = {}; for (var i in obj) { if (keys.indexOf(i) >= 0) continue; if (!Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, i)) continue; target[i] = obj[i]; } return target; }

var Label = function Label(props) {
  var id = props.id,
      className = props.className,
      children = props.children,
      other = _objectWithoutProperties(props, ['id', 'className', 'children']);

  return _react2.default.createElement(
    'label',
    _extends({ id: id, className: className }, other),
    children
  );
};

exports.default = Label;


Label.propTypes = {
  id: _propTypes2.default.string,
  className: _propTypes2.default.string,
  children: _propTypes2.default.node
};

Label.defaultProps = {
  id: '',
  className: '',
  children: null
};

/***/ })
/******/ ]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found an answer by [Michael Jungo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6447491/michael-jungo) in a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44542254/4513747

> A webpack bundle does not expose your exports by default, as it
>   assumes that you're building an app and not a library (which is the
>   far more common use of webpack). You can create a library by
>   configuring `output.library` and `output.libraryTarget`

The documentation at https://webpack.js.org/guides/author-libraries, walks you through the process of using webpack for bundling a library.

Using the output in `webpack.config.js` as in the following, exposes the `export`s when bundling.

```
output: {
  path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
  filename: '[name]/index.js',
  library: 'yourLibraryName',
  libraryTarget: 'umd',
},
```

More information on this can be found at https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#output-library