# Class (module) is not exported

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack

Module:

```js
import typeIs from './helpers/typeIs';

/**
 * @description Class of checking and throwing a custom exception.
 */
export default class Inspector {
// Some code
}
```

In `package.json` specified the path to the file:

```
{
// ....
"main": "dist/app.js",
// ...
}
```

I install the package locally using the command `npm install ../ PACKAGE DIRECTORY /`. Everything is installed, but the console returns `{}`. What could be the problem?

Returns an empty object exactly in the minified file (`dist / app.js`). And if you connect the source - it works.

`.babelrc`:

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"],

  "env": {
    "test": {
      "plugins": ["transform-es2015-modules-commonjs"]
    }
  }
}
```

`package.json`:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.10.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.10.4",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.1.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs": "^6.26.2",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.2",
    "eslint": "^7.5.0",
    "eslint-config-google": "^0.14.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^4.0.2",
    "jest": "^26.1.0",
    "webpack": "^4.44.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12"
  },
  "browserslist": "> 0.25%, not dead",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.10.4"
  }
```

> **UPD** *I check so*

```js
const Inspector = require('inspector-with-exceptions');

console.dir(Inspector);
```

Comment: "*the console returns `{}`*" - when doing what?

Comment: Which of `exports = {…};`, `exports['…'] = …;` and `module.exports = …;` do you actually have in your code? The first one does not work.

Comment: Why are you using `transform-es2015-modules-commonjs` when not writing ES6 module syntax?

Comment: Oh, that's a different question now :-) Try `require('inspector-with-exceptions').default`, or use ES6 module syntax for the import as well: `import Inspector from 'inspector-with-exceptions';`.

Comment: @Bergi Does not work(

Comment: What's the error message you get when you try that? What does the transpiled commonjs module look like?

Comment: @Bergi `const Inspector = require('inspector-with-exceptions').default;` return `undefined;`,  and  `import Inspector from ''inspector-with-exceptions''` throw `SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`

Comment: Don't use double apostrophes?

Comment: @Bergi I use everywhere `'`.

Comment: [Check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44541561/webpack-output-is-empty-object)

Answer (score 1):

One of the common errors in importing modules is forgetting to make them relative. The difference between `require('inspector-with-exceptions')` and `require('./inspector-with-exceptions')` is that first one looks your node_modules and the second looks your file system. I think the problem in your code is that.

Edit: I have quite a lot had this problem since last week. Luckily I found the way to solve it. So the easiest way to handle this issue is to make your output property in webpack.config.js like below:

```js
//Rest of you webpack file
output: {
  path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  filename: <project-name>.js,
  libraryTarget: 'commonjs2',
  libraryExport: 'default',
  library: <ProjectName>
}
```

Use the cases as  I have shown in <>. Hope this helps.

Comment: answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44541561/webpack-output-is-empty-object